# How to properly synchronize desktop and mobile app in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, project, topic-modeling

I would like to build an application to foreign languages learning, something based on creating decks with flashcards, words ordering, add voice (pronounciation) samples, add images etc. (something similar to ANKI app).

I want to use C# language and .NET platform to make it. I wish make both desktop and mobile app (maybe also website, but this is to be considered). And my question is what exactly technologies (type of projects) should I use to do it?
It means I should make desktop app using .net framework with WPF and Xamarin to mobile app and then somehow synchronize it? I would like to synchronize desktop and mobile apps together - if someone uses desktop version and then install mobile app then he/she could have access to the whole his/her previous decks/settings and so on, maybe should I consider creating accounts?
But I also wonder about the .net core and thanks to that I would make my app to be cross-platfrom.

I don't know how to correctly plan it ... Another thing is I would like to use some python libaries in that, exactly I mean gensim and generally topic-modeling, maybe also some other tools to neural networks. In general I would like to embed python things in my C# code.

Sumarizing, the aim is to create both desktop and mobile app using .net (.net framework or .net core), somehow makes the synchronization/connection between them and then (like a additional feature) use some python topic-modelling and neural network tools to enrich this whole app with some things. 
Would you recommend me something, some way to do it properly (some good approach to the topic), where should I start?
Till now I was using mainly wpf/win forms, also entity framework, ado.net and so on. I have never used .net core but I think it's time to get to know that - it's future I suppose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using Xamarin Forms is a good approach to target Android/iOS/Windows.

As for maintaining state (flash cards, etc) between multiple apps/platforms, you will need your users to create account. Dotnet core is an excellent choice for your api. You can decide to go with a monolith or micro-service arch with it.

As for using python, dotnet core allows you load and use python scripts from C# code. You should take a look at IronPython and how to host the interpreter in the dotnet core code.

All in all, the stack looks good, but you need to understand that more important than the stack is your overall architecture, how everything ties together.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for reply. And would you somehow help me to get a proper direction? You said about tying everything together and I think that's the main point. Can you show me some idea/approach to do it properly. Now I know that good choice will be .NET core and Xamarin forms (and also creating user account in my application to be able to get all user data etc) but from where I should start? Have I create Xamarin app and separetly .NET core project (like desktop app and whole service/api) and then comunicate between these two. Maybe using WCF will be good in this case?

Comment: I don't have an experience with any Web APIs, generally some servers and so on. I have done only pure desktop apps, also some simple database apps and games (unity). Now, I want to make this app and I need some simple (but also a proper/good) way to make it :)